# Doctrine 2 multi-level inheritance - how to define the join

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql, discriminator

I have two tables:

Email:

```
id    message
1     This is an email message
```

Activity:

```
id    related_id    related_type
66    1             email
72    1             booking
74    55            booking
```

In a query builder I want to join Email.id to Activity.related_id **only** if related_type is 'email'.

I therefore have Entity Activity:

```
/**
 * Activity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="activity")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="related_type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap( {"email" = "Email"} )
 */
class Activity
```

And Entity Email:

```
/**
 * Email
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="email", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="contact_id_index", columns={"contact_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Cinolla\ApiBundle\Entity\EmailRepository")
 */
class Email extends Activity
```

However, looking at the query that doctrine is generating at the moment, it's doing:

`FROM email t0 INNER JOIN activity t1 ON t0.id = t1.id`

Whereas it should be doing:

`FROM email t0 INNER JOIN activity t1 ON t1.related_id = t0.id AND t1.related_type = 'email'`

- Where do I define that Email should be joined on related_id?
- Why has it not included the `AND t1.related_type = 'email'`?

Comment: So, what type of queries have you written for the QueryBuilder? Or have you used Criteria? As you're using Discriminator classes, why do you not simply get Email instances? Else, get Activity via Repository and then use the `filter()` function on the resulting Collection instance (when getting using `matching()`)?

Comment: Also, a Discriminator 'extends' parent Entity. A bit like plain PHP classes really. As such, with the code you've provided, an `Email` Entity **IS** an `Activity` Entity, as such, you need not provide a bit in the query for `type = 'email'`. You might be mixing relations (`OneToMany` probably for this use-case) with discriminators?

Comment: Lastly, if you're defining a `DiscriminatorMap` yourself (you are in your code), then you must provide the map for all classes. In your code your missing the definition for `"activity" = Activity` in the map. Note that in the docs it's stated that you **can** define a DiscriminatorMap, but it's not required (if not set, Doctrine will generate it for you).